# How to detect value in array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have array of hashes:

```
@array = [{:id => "1", :status=>"R"},
      {:id => "1", :status=>"R"},
      {:id => "1", :status=>"B"},
      {:id => "1", :status=>"R"}]
```

How to detect, does it contain in hashes with the value of status "B"? Like in simply array:

```
@array = ["R","R","B","R"]
puts "Contain B" if @array.include?("B")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
@array.any? { |h| h[:status] == "B" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays (enumerables actually) have a `detect` method. It returns a `nil` if it doesn't detect anything, so you can use it like Andrew Marshall's `any`.

```
@array = [{:id => "1", :status=>"R"}, 
      {:id => "1", :status=>"R"}, 
      {:id => "1", :status=>"B"}, 
      {:id => "1", :status=>"R"}] 
puts "Has status B" if @array.detect{|h| h[:status] == 'B'}
```

Comment: I'd only really use `detect` over `any?` if I cared about finding the values that match the criteria as well, but it can certainly be used as a predicate method. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what steenslag said:

`detect` ***doesn't always return nil.***

You can pass in a lambda to execute (call) if detect does not 'detect' (find) an item. In other words, you can tell `detect` what to do if it can't detect (find) something.

To add to your example:

```
not_found = lambda { "uh oh. couldn't detect anything!"}
# try to find something that isn't in the Enumerable object:
@array.detect(not_found) {|h| h[:status] == 'X'}
```

will return `"uh oh. couldn't detect anything!"`

This means that you don't have to write this kind of code:

```
if (result = @array.detect {|h| h[:status] == 'X'}).nil?
    # show some error, do something here to handle it
    #    (this would be the behavior you'd put into your lambda)
else
   # deal nicely with the result
end
```

That's one major difference between `any?` and `detect` -- you can't tell `any?` what to do if it doesn't find any items.

This is in the Enumerable class.  ref: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003123